# What are these characters called: 。. !？etc Trying to split sentences stops working with non standard characters

Tags: python

I am trying to split sentences by . ? ! etc, but in some languages they have non standard character. For example english . and japanese 。

What is the name of these characters so that I can just add all of different varieties in my sentence split method.

Comment: These are called punctuation characters or special characters.

Comment: There are tables for Unicode characters, like [this one](https://unicode-table.com/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506869/are-there-character-collections-for-all-international-full-stop-punctuations

Comment: How does knowing the name of the characters help with the split method? Or are you actually asking for a *list* of characters that can end a sentence?

Answer (score 2):

That is a unicode character.  In Japanese, it's what is known as a [full stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_punctuation#Full_stop).  It has Unicode U+3002.

```
In [8]: print(u'\u3002')
。
```

Therefore to split based on this character in Python:

```
l = s.split(u'\u3002')
```

`l` would be a list of strings split by the full stop delimiter found in the string `s`.

Answer (score 0):

[In Japanese the '。' is called a kuten. In English meaning 'full stop'.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_punctuation#Full_stop)

You can split a sentence with any character. I would look up the punctuation for the language you are working with and copy they utf-8 character that you wanted to use.

```
>>> str = "私は擬人です。それを水ですか？"
>>> for x in str.split("。"):
...     print(x)
... 
私は擬人です
それを水ですか？
```

[For other languages you can loop up their punctuation as well.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation)