# Javascript all dots replace with space (Why my code is not working)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace all . with space.

I am done with regex

```js
var voice = "I am student of …… School"
voice = voice.replace(/(~|`|!|@|#|$|%|^|&|\*|\(|\)|{|}|\[|\]|;|:|\"|'|<|,|\.|>|\?|\/|\\|\||-|_|\+|=)/g, "");
console.log(voice)
```

It returns `"I am a student of the .... university"`

but I want a string like this => `"I am a student of the university"`

Comment: That is not what it returns.

Comment: Made you a snippet. Your code does what you ask it to do. You may want to change two spaces to one as well

Comment: so basically you only want letters and spaces to be left in the string?

Comment: if yes, you might be better off with `voice.match(/\w+/g).join(' ')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works when you subsequently replace multiple spaces with one space

```js
var voice = "I am student of the .....University, not the …… School"
console.log(voice)
voice = voice.replace(/(~|`|!|@|#|$|%|^|&|\*|\(|\)|{|}|\[|\]|;|:|\"|'|<|,|\.|…|>|\?|\/|\\|\||-|_|\+|=)/g, "")
             .replace(/ +/g," "); // or /\s+/g
console.log(voice)
```

If you keep coming up with more punctuation then you have a never ending issue:

[Are there character collections for all international full stop punctuations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506869/are-there-character-collections-for-all-international-full-stop-punctuations)

So maybe this is better:

```js
var voice = "I am student of the .....University, not the …… School"
console.log(voice)
voice = voice.replace(/\W/g, " ")
             .replace(/ +/g," "); // or /\s+/g
console.log(voice)
```

Comment: this is not working for  "I am student of …… School"

Comment: Your full stops are not full stops, but ellipsis

Comment: I added ellipsis to the list of stuff. `|…|`

Comment: @RahulJat we can imagine more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506869/are-there-character-collections-for-all-international-full-stop-punctuations

Comment: @RahulJat - Please ensure when you ask a question that the information you provide is accurate. Notice that **five different people** in this thread offered their time to try to help you, only to find that you'd given incorrect test data in the question.

Comment: Sorry, there does not happen again. @mplungjan

Answer (score 2):

You may try this

```js
var voice =  "I am a student of the .... university."
voice = voice.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ')

console.log(voice);
```

Comment: var voice = voice.replace(/\./g, '')console.log('voice',voice)

Comment: That leaves two spaces between "the" and "university".

Comment: Your update *still* leaves two space between "the" and "university", but will remove two spaces (entirely) *elsewhere* in the string, possibly ending up joining words together. For instance, `"I am a student  at the .... university"` (two spaces after `student`) becomes `"I am a studentat the  university"` (no spaces after `student`, two of them between `the` and `university`).

Comment: actually string comes from the database, my query is how to remove all dots from string

Comment: This answer (like mine) answers the question that was originally asked, but it's been edited now. It turns out the OP gave us incorrect sample data. i recommend deleting the answer (since there's already an accepted one).

Answer (score 1):

In any case you don't like regex. Not much bad in performance too.

```
var voice = "I am a student of the .... university."
voice  = voice .split('.').join(' ');
```

Comment: This will leave multiple space

Comment: This answer (like mine) answers the question that was originally asked, but it's been edited now. It turns out the OP gave us incorrect sample data. i recommend deleting the answer (since there's already an accepted one).